# How to iterate through Swift array and use data in iOS Chart?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, charts, ios-charts

I have a bar chart, which I am trying to populate through data pulled in from an array.

I am trying to iterate through this array in order to populate my chart.

**Please note:** in this example below there are 3 winningStreakDM variables hardcoded for testing purposes, but in 'real life' the number could be different each API call as it depends on how many 'users' are in that league.

This is why I need to iterate through the array and structure the data to suit.

```
    let winningStreakDM1 : [String : Any] = [
        "id" : 2,
        "user_name" : "Dicky",
        "winning_streak" : 5
    ]

    let winningStreakDM2 : [String : Any] = [
        "id" : 6,
        "user_name" : "G",
        "winning_streak" : 2
    ]

    let winningStreakDM3 : [String : Any] = [
        "id" : 5,
        "user_name" : "Sultan",
        "winning_streak" : 0
    ]
```

My issue is that I don't know how to iterate through the initial array to structure my data for it to work with the above code.

This is my full script:

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class CommunityLeagueStatsVC: UIViewController {


// GRAPHS *********

@IBOutlet weak var chartView: BarChartView!
var values = [BarChartDataEntry]()

// ****************
//********CHART VARIABLES**************//

//WINS LOSSES DRAWS
var winStreak: Double = 0.0

@IBOutlet weak var leagueStatsScrollView: UIScrollView!

var noDefeats: Bool?
var noWins: Bool?
var biggestWin: String?
var biggestWinTeams: String?

var passedCommunityName: String?
@IBOutlet weak var communityName: UILabel!

var playerId2: String?
var communityId2: String?
var eMail2: String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


    let winningStreak =  ["Wins"]
    let gamesWon = [winStreak]
    setWinStreakChart(dataPoints: winningStreak, values: gamesWon)

    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let Email = defaults.string(forKey: "userEmail")
    let playerId = defaults.string(forKey: "playerId")
    let commsId = defaults.string(forKey: "communityId")

    self.playerId2 = playerId
    self.communityId2 = commsId
    self.eMail2 = Email


}

 func setWinStreakChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [BarChartDataEntry]){

    xAxis.valueFormatter = WinningStreakFormatter(chartView: self.chartView)
    let barChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: values, label: "Winning Streak")
    barChartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()

    let barChartData = BarChartData(dataSet: barChartDataSet)
    barChartData.setValueFont(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0))
    self.chartView.data = barChartData
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    let myUrl = URL(string: "http://www.xxx.uk/xxx/getLeagueStats.php")
    var request = URLRequest(url:myUrl!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"

    let postString = "player_id=\(self.playerId2!)&community_id=\(communityId2!)";

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8);
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data: Data?, response: URLResponse?, error: Error?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async
            {
                do{

                    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String:AnyObject]
                    print (json!)

                       if let dict = json?["leagueStats"] as? [String:AnyObject] {

                          //WINNING STREAK

                        var values = [BarChartDataEntry]()

                        if let dataWinStreak = dict["winningStreak"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                            print ("test one")
                            for (index,item) in dataWinStreak.enumerated() {
                                if let yValue = item["winning_streak"] as? Int, let userName = item["user_name"] as? String {
                                    print ("test two")
                                    let barChartDataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: Double(yValue), data: userName as AnyObject?)
                                    values.append(barChartDataEntry)

                                }
                            }

                            self.setWinStreakChart(dataPoints: ["wins"], values: values)
                        }
        catch{
            print(error)
                }
        }
        }
    task.resume()

}
}
```

**UPDATE:**

**These are the errors that I am currently receiving:**

[image]

[image]
[image]

With a bit of playing around and commenting out the line containing the first error I have got to this stage which correctly shows a graph with values, but no xAxis containing the userNames of each player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create array of `BarChartDataEntry` this way.

```
var values = [BarChartDataEntry]()

if let dataWinStreak = dict["winningStreak"] as? [[String : Any]] {
    for (index,item) in dataWinStreak.enumerated() {
        if let yValue = item["winning_streak"] as? Int, let userName = item["user_name"] as? String {
            let barChartDataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: index, y: yValue, data: userName)
            values.append(barChartDataEntry)
        }
    }
}
//Now use values array
```

**Edit:** You just need to change `setWinStreakChart` function because now you are working with dynamic data not static one.

```
func setWinStreakChart(dataPoints: [String], values: [BarChartDataEntry]){

    let  xAxis : XAxis = self.chartView.xAxis;
    xAxis.labelFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Light", size: 10.0)!
    xAxis.labelTextColor = UIColor.black
    xAxis.drawAxisLineEnabled = false
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    xAxis.granularity = 1;
    xAxis.labelPosition = .bottom

    xAxis.valueFormatter = WinningStreakFormatter(chartView: self.chartView)
    let barChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: values, label: "Winning Streak")
    barChartDataSet.colors = ChartColorTemplates.material()

    let barChartData = BarChartData(dataSet: barChartDataSet)
    barChartData.setValueFont(UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12.0))
    self.chartView.data = barChartData
}
```

And now call this function after the for loop where we are creating array of `BarChartDataEntry`.

```
self.setWinStreakChart(dataPoints: ["wins"], values: values)
```

Comment: I have an error in that I have added this line ` self.setWinStreakChart(dataPoints: ["wins"], values: values)` to the bottom of your code to then call the function but it says ' Cannot convert value of type '[BarChartDataEntry]' to expected argument type '[Double]'.  I have updated the question to show the full function and what it is expecting.  Thank you!

Comment: @RDowns Why are you calling that function your array of BarChartDataEntry is created so don't you need to call now: `let barChartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(values: values, label: "Winning Streak")`

Comment: The api call happens outside of the function to create the chart- so don't I need to call the function to populate it with the data retrieved? I should probably show you the full script- I am out at the moment but will update the question with the full script when I return. Thanks

Comment: I have added my full script to the question so you can see what I mean - and hopefully where I am going wrong!

Comment: it's failing because it is expecting Doubles and not Integers.  It is auto-suggesting corrections, but ultimately fails - I have updated the question with the progress.  Thanks again, appreciate your help

Comment: @RDowns You need to change your `setWinStreakChart` like my one and set values type to array of `BarChartDataEntry` instead of Array of `Double`.

Comment: Thanks @NiravD I have done what you said (I believe) but I am still getting this error relating to expecting a Double and not an Int.  I have updated my code above and have included a screenshot to show you my error.

Comment: I changed the line: `if let yValue = item["winning_streak"] as? Int`, to say `as? String` and the graph has appeared - I am still having an issue showing the X-axis though as I had to comment it out to get rid of the error as shown in the updated question.  I also had to change to this line: `let barChartDataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(index), y: Double(yValue)!, data: userName as AnyObject?)` which is probably part of the issue.

Comment: @RDowns I'm currently out from Mac will help you tomorrow.

Comment: thank you your help has been invaluable - that has corrected all of my issues.